# Erro na indentação em python

Tags: python

Eu já programo em c, estou mdc em Python porém estou com dificuldades com a indentação, pois em c a gente não se preocupa com isso, alguém poderia me ajudar, meu código abaixo

```
numero = int(input())
for i in range():
  x = int(input())
  n = int(input())
    int resto = x % n
    while(resto!=0)
        x = n
        n = resto
        resto = x % n
print(n2)
```

Comment: Amigo tem várias coisas mal com o seu código antes da identação, não precisa declarar o tipo da varíavel `int` na quinta linha, não existe `:` no while `while(condicao):` e também não existe a variavel `n2`. Á primeira vista, parece ser os erros que tem. A identação aconselho a usar tab.

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

Basicamente sobre a indentação em python, é ela que define o bloco de instruções a ser executada por determinada instrução de controle (laço de repetição, condições, etc). Ela se assemelha as chaves usadas em C, javascript, PHP.

Sobre seu exemplo especificamente, ele de fato possui alguns probleminhas com sintaxe e indentação. Sugiro dar uma verificada em https://www.python.org/doc/ para dar uma pegada no básico.